# hitTest getting called twice for the same event in NSCell

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsoutlineview, hittest, custom-cell

I'm working on a subclass of NSTextFieldCell for my project.

This subclass has, in some situation a NSButtonCell drawn on its view, with this :

```
-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView{

       if(self.isPresent){

           [_button.cell drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
       }
 ....     
}
```

And I am Implementing the hitTest

```
- (NSUInteger)hitTestForEvent:(NSEvent *)event inRect:(NSRect)frame ofView:(NSView *)controlView {

    NSLog(@"hitTest !");

    .............

     hitType |= NSCellHitTrackableArea;


     return hitType;

}
```

But my problem is when ever the hitTest is satisfied hitTestForEvent: is getting called

twice everytime for the same event type LeftMouseDown which is quite strange. As result I am

getting unexpected result . I just want hitTestForEvent: to be called only once , for

LeftMouseDown Event .Any help is appreciated .

Comment: The same thing happens in iOS when users tap on a view. If I recall correctly it's called twice on iOS 7 and thrice before that. `hitTest` is not the place to do manipulation. The purpose is to let the responder chain know to what it needs to respond.